# Separation of sister chromatids diring anaphase without Centrosomes in plant cell during mitosis

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, mitosis

As in animal cell during mitosis sister chromatids are separated from each other during Anaphase by the pulling of kinetochore fibers toward their originating poles of centrosomes but as we know that Plant cells lack centrosome or centrioles then how sister chromatids are separated in plant cells from each other?